# SVF vs SVF2 Conversionfrom BIM 360 to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Our current version software takes files from BIM360 and converts them to SVF to view in unity on our app
What would happen if we just convert to SVF2 instead or SVF from BIM 360 DOCs?
Any reason we cannot do that from BIM 360 DOCs?

We are having issue with DBIDs not synching up based on a recent release from Autodesk

The other option is this article from Peter Broz that might apply to our situation

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/temporary-workaround-mapping-between-svf1-and-svf2-ids

Answer (score 0):

OTG and SVF2 are the same thing, just using a different server – OTG is the legacy SVF2. It is a fine detail which isn’t important in your case, but sometimes has its importance as I demoed it yesterday in the Viewer. Petr’s article is exactly what I was mentioning yesterday about the dbid.idx file, but within the Viewer. My suggestion is that you server download that file and do the mapping on your back-end. But if you feel doing the conversion from the Viewer is better for you, that’s ok too and Petr’s article is the way to go.

Now, when you are on BIM360, you cannot force the target format, neither you can choose which format is used for the extraction. As I said, it is either OTG or SVF2 (even if SVF is present since both OTG and SVF2 are post-process of SVF), but the target extraction is OTG / SVF2 – that means Model Derivative will always use SVF2 dbid, and you have no option there.

Exporting to OBJ using Model Derivative will use SVF2 dbid. That’s why you know need to do some mapping since the toolkit works exclusively with SVF. This problem was unexpected, because the toolkit return you all geometries, material and textures, and I did not knew you were not using that feature which would have saved you from this issue.

Comment: How do we synch the SVF and SVF2 as the SVF file when pulled into unity only has the DBID and to other data to synch to the SVF2?
We are having trouble finding/seeing the common element between the SVF and SVF2 DBID to make the cross reference
We assume it would be the GUID, but it does not come into Unity?

Comment: GUIDs are coming into Unity as external_id in the property sets - Forge uses external_ids as Revit uses GUID, AutoCAD uses HANDLE, etc... Another alternative is to get the SVF <-> SVF2 DB ID Mapping file, so you can convert them on the fly. But using external_id should work.